# How to remove last symbol from content of an element?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

I have a filed made of div: `<div class="field"></div>`
There symbols appear between div tags as I type, now I'm trying to implement button that removes last symbol (backspace).

Previously I used this to append element to a string inside of div: `$(".field").append(divContent);`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try:

```
$(".field").text($(".field").text().slice(0, -1));
```